# CentOS 6.5 - PHP 5.6.7 and bcmath

Tags: php, linux, apache, bcmath

I am trying to install php-bcmath on CentOS 6.5 and my current PHP Version is 5.6.7. The reason why I'm trying to install this is because I have a plugin for my forum which I am using that throws off errors due to my server using the most recent PHP version. The error it's throwing is listed below:

> Flags/Listener/Includes/Reader/Decoder.php on line 258, referer:
>   http://IP Address/admin.php
>
> [Tue Apr 07 03:42:15 2015] [error] [client IP Address] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Countryflags\Db\Reader\bcadd() in /var/www/html/library/Snog/CountryFlags/Listener/Includes/Reader/Decoder.php on line 258, referer: http://IP Address/admin.php
>
> [Tue Apr 07 03:45:50 2015] [error] [client IP Address] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Countryflags\Db\Reader\bcadd() in /var/www/html/library/Snog/CountryFlags/Listener/Includes/Reader/Decoder.php on line 258
>
> [Tue Apr 07 03:45:56 2015] [error] [client IP Address] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Countryflags\Db\Reader\bcadd() in /var/www/html/library/Snog/CountryFlags/Listener/Includes/Reader/Decoder.php on line 258

So when I try installing php-bcmath on my server via yum install, I get:

> [root@forums logs]# yum install php-bcmath Loaded plugins:
>   fastestmirror, replace Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   * base: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
>   * extras: mirror.oss.ou.edu
>   * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
>   * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com Setting up Install Process Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-bcmath-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
>   --> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.7-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common 5.5.0
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles
>   --nodigest [root@forums logs]#

Are there any ways to get the installation working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `yum install php-bcmath --skip-broken`?

Comment: Will this still install everything properly or skip over what can't be installed?

Comment: This is not programming related, but rather installation help. Flagged for migration to a more appropriate site.  At first glance it seems you have some non-official repositories enabled which are both trying to provide the same package; resulting in a conflict where a package needs to be installed from the core repository but is available from the alternate one.

Comment: Fixed the issue. I'm using webtatic repo to get the latest PHP version. I went ahead and removed the standard PHP modules (`yum remove php*`) and then used `yum install php56w-bcmath` and it worked.